# How to actually calculate the probability to have extracted each one of $n$ balls at least once after $k$ turns?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, binomial-coefficients, coupon-collector

I have a bowl of $n$ balls numbered $1$ to $n$. I will perform $k$ extractions (with immediate replacement into the bowl after extraction). I want to calculate the probability to have extracted each ball at least once after those $k$ turns.

With inclusion/exclusion principle from [Probability to see all 6 numbers on a die after n throws](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1871408/probability-to-see-all-6-numbers-on-a-die-after-n-throws) for example, I arrived at:

$$P(n, k) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (-1)^{n-i} \binom{n}{i} i^k \frac{1}{n^{k}}$$

But this takes forever to calculate for something like $n=50$, $k=1000$. Can I further simplify this equation? Is the equation even correct?

Comment: do you mean : " $k$ extractions with replacement (upon each extraction)"?

Comment: well, it makes more clear that you are are extracting one ball and put it back before extracting the next. You could extract two or three , etc. balls before restoring them, although from the rest of the statement it is clear that $n \le k$

Comment: @GCab Thanks :) I tried to improve the question text. Is that what you meant?

Comment: yes, now it is more clear

Answer (score 2):

Your formula is correct. It can't be further simplified, except perhaps by expressing it in terms of the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind):

$$
\def\stir#1#2{\left\{#1\atop#2\right\}}
P(n,k)=\frac{k!}{n^k}\stir kn\;.
$$

There are other ways to calculate this probability (for instance by keeping track of the probability distribution over the number of distinct balls seen and updating it $k$ times), but I'd be surprised if any of them took less than the $O(kn)$ steps that evaluating your equation takes.